# C# compiler bug, Returning a different value then expected, show correct in debugging but return wrong value

Tags: c#, string, debugging

In my C# function I take the dynamic parameter. Look for ID property otherwise take postid property. In this code you can see it's showing 1567 value but it's returning 1614.

Am I missing something, or I am doing it some wrong way. please someone help.

[image]

```
 public static string URL(dynamic post)
        {
            string link = "";
            int Id = 0;
            if (post?.link != null)
                link = post.link;
            else if (post?.Slug != null)
                link = post.Slug;
            if (post.ID != null)
                Id = post.ID;
            else if (post.postid != null)
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(post.postid);

            return '/' + Id + "-" + link + ".html";
        }
```

Comment: Could you provide the full method body? In text.

Comment: @john please find the updated question

Comment: Gotta love the attitude. Sure, it's much more likely that the Roslyn team have a bug then you. After all, you're You!
I'm not saying that c# is bug free (or any product, for that matter, by any software developer)  - but much more often the fault is with the programmer misunderstanding some aspect of the language (or the .Net framework).

Comment: @ZoharPeled Since I am doing most of my work in C# & JavaScript, I did't notice the single quote before I see the answer, see I even type "" in Watch window.

Comment: That's not my point at all. If you search Stackoverflow `[c#] Bug` you'll see what I mean - most of the questions asking about bugs in c# are actually developers that makes a mistake in their code since they misunderstood how something in c# or the .Net framework should work.

Answer (score 7):

`'/'` is 47 decimal.
1567 + 47 = 1614. Try using `"/"` instead. (note double quotes)